# Write jump instruction in c

Tags: c, assembly

To preface this, yes this is a project to take control of an executable externally.  No, I do not have any malicious intents with this, the end result of this project won't be anything useful anyway.  I am writing this in cygwin on a 32-bit installation of XP.

What I need to do is change the first few bits of a COM file to be a jump instruction so that on execution, it will jump to the very end of the COM file.  I have looked in Assembler manuals to find what the bytes of that command would be so that I can just hard code it in C, but have had no luck.

First Question: Can I do this in C?  It seems to me like I could just insert OpCodes in the beginning of any COM file so that it would execute that instead of the COM file.

Second Question: does someone know where I can find a resource for OpCodes so that I can insert them in my file?  Or, does anyone know what the bytes would be for a Jump instruction?

If you have any question about the authenticity of this, feel free to ask.

Comment: Add more detail on your platform.  Do you really mean a 16 bit DOS "COM" file?  If so, the instructions begin right at the first byte of the file.  Just insert your jump there, and either parse the instruction you clobbered so you can recreate it in your stub or just hope that it doesn't matter.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes I do mean a 16 bit DOS "COM" file.  But was I asked was for specifics on "insert your jump there".  That is what I cannot figure out.  Do you have specifics on that?

Comment: Have you tried googling "x86 instruction set"?

Comment: It's a valid and interesting question. Why does everyone downvote this? One of the better ways to learn about assembly and machine code is actually to experiment with this stuff.

Comment: @Nikos C.: That question is downvoted, because it is not precise enough (16 bits DOS COM was not mentioned in the question), and because a lot of answers are easily searchable on the web.

Comment: If you think that this is easily searchable on the web then I would encourage you to post a quick link.  It is possible that my extensive searching may have been done poorly, but I think I did well and still failed to find anything useful.
And 16 bit DOS COM file was assumed.  If you thought I was referring to some 32 bit COM file I am sorry.

Comment: I did answer to your question and I did add a link (to wikipedia, and to relevant libraries). They gibe other links directly answering your question.

Comment: There's some virtue in trying to tackle an impossible task and having no clue how to go about it, learning as you get along.  That however just doesn't work well when you ask others to help you, they'll just flip you the bird and tell you "dude, you have no idea what you are getting into".  Like any Internet Q+A site.

Comment: Your links are helpful, but they do not answer my question.  Finding what the bytes of a jump instruction are from that does not seem possible.  If it is, however, please correct me.

Comment: If the answer is "I do not know" I would appreciate that much more than downvotes and complaints that this is a trivial answer to find.

Comment: The [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manual Volume 2A Instruction Set Reference](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) contains the encoding of the JMP instruction (real mode is a subset of IA-32).  For a 16-byte near jump (within the current code segment) you'd use `0xE9` followed by the relative offset to jump to.  If your jump is the first bytes of the COM file then the offset will be relative to address `0x103`.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much.  More than just the specific byte values, this gives me a concrete context to learn more about the assembly instructions as relevant explanations are right by the details about the jump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manual Volume 2A Instruction Set Reference](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) explains the encoding of the `JMP` instruction (real mode is a subset of IA-32).

For a 16-byte near jump (within the current code segment) you'd use `0xE9` followed by the relative offset to jump to. If your jump is the first bytes of the COM file then the offset will be relative to address `0x103` - the first instruction of a COM file is always loaded at address `0x100`, and the jump is relative to the instruction following the 3-byte jump.

Answer (score 1):

On XP there should be debug.exe. Simply start it, start writing code with 'a'
type jmp ff00, and dis/[u]nassemble the result with 'u' if the corresponding hex dump was not shown.

Answer (score 0):

Notice first that your program is necessarily operating system, ABI, and machine instruction set specific. (e.g. it won't run under Linux/x86-64 or Linux/PowerPC)

You could write in *C* the machine instructions as a sequence of bytes. Which bytes you have to write (i.e. the encoding of the appropriate jump instructions) is left to you!!!!!

Of course, that is not portable C. But you could basically do a `memcpy` with some appropriate source byte zone.

Maybe libraries like [asmjit](http://code.google.com/p/asmjit/) or [GNU lightning](http://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/) might inspire you.

<sup>You probably cannot use them directly, but studying their code could help you.</sup>

See also [x86](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) wikipedia pages for more references.

Comment: Thank your for replying.  The part that you said is left me, however, is exactly what I am asking.  A resource to find out what those bytes are.  For instance, will an X86 manual have this information?  I don't think it does, but I would love to be corrected.

Comment: Definitely, the Intel x86 instruction set manual do have that information, and both GNU Lightning and asmjit also give that. And the wikipedia page gives directly a link giving that information.

Comment: I am confused as to how generating assembly code (as asmjit and GNU Lightning do) from C/C++ will give me the OpCodes for a jump instruction.  It seems to me like that is going in the opposite direction, I would need to know how to write a jump in C to get an output of assembly.

Comment: Notice that `asmjit` & `lightning` both generate *machine* code, not *assembler* code (like `gcc` does thru its `cc1`). And you also need to generate the *machine* code doing your jump. So they are related to your issue (the difference is that you want to generate a 16bit mode jump).